# MultIpointtoucharea in QML: How to mimick Mac OS-like gestures

Tags: qt, qml

I have been trying to implement the thumb + two-finger gestures used on the Mac mousepad to bring up the main menu of my app. I am having difficulty registering the opposite directions taken by the thumb and fingers and creating a signal handler for when a suitable event occurs. I have tried splitting the window into two to allow two multipointtouch areas, one (bottom) for thumb and the other (top half) for the fingers but that is utterly non-functional. Here is my test code so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.0




Rectangle {
    id: mainView
    //    width: 600
    //    height: 900
    Rectangle {
        x: 24
        y: 14
        z:2
        width: 666
        height: 560
        color: "#ffa800"

        Text {
            z:2
            font.pointSize: 12
            id: logTxt1
             text:
                 "distance traversed :"+ (touch1.y - touch1.startY)

            x: 8
            y: 8
            height: 68
            width: 144
            function log(txt){
                text = txt+"\n"
            }
        }
            Text {
                 font.pointSize: 12
                z:2
                id: logTxt2
                 text:
                      "distance traversed :"+ (touch2.y - touch2.startY)
                x: 8
                y: 98
                height: 58
                width: 165
                function log(txt){
                    text = txt+"\n"
                }
            }

                Text {
                    z:2
                     font.pointSize: 12
                    id: logTxt3
                     text:
                          "distance traversed :"+ (touch3.y - touch3.startY)

                    x: 11
                    y: 180
                    height: 68
                    width: 141
                    function log(txt){
                        text = txt+"\n"
                    }
                }
                    Text {
                         font.pointSize: 12
                        z:2
                        id: logTxt4
                         text:
                              "distance traversed :"+ (touch4.y - touch4.startY)
                        x: 20
                        y: 266
                        height: 68
                        width: 137
                        function log(txt){
                            text = txt+"\n"
                        }
        }
                    Text {
                        z:2
                         font.pointSize: 12
                        id: logTxt5
                        text:
                             "distance traversed :"+ (touch5.y-touch5.startY)
                        x: 24
                        y: 362
                        height: 58
                        width: 134
                        function log(txt){
                            text = txt+"\n"
                        }
    }

    Text {
        id: message
        x: 20
        y: 454
        width: 380
        height: 49
        text: qsTr("Text")
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
            }


    VisualItemModel {
        id: itemModel
        Rectangle { z:3; anchors.fill: parent; color: "red" }
        Rectangle { z:1; anchors.fill: parent;
            Rectangle {

                height: 200
                width : 600
                color: "yellow"
            }

            color: "#028000" }
        Rectangle { z: 1; anchors.fill: parent; color: "#0500ff" }
    }


    MultiPointTouchArea {
        id: multiGest
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height *0.5

        anchors.topMargin: mainView.top
        minimumTouchPoints: 2
        maximumTouchPoints: 4
        touchPoints: [
            TouchPoint { id: touch1 },
            TouchPoint { id: touch2 },
            TouchPoint { id: touch3 },
            TouchPoint { id: touch4 }

        ]


   }
    MultiPointTouchArea {
        id: multiGest2
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height *0.5

        anchors.bottomMargin: mainView.bottom
        minimumTouchPoints: 1
        maximumTouchPoints: 1
        touchPoints: [
            TouchPoint { id: touch5 }


        ]


   }
    }
```